# Adding <button> tag in Rendering Variants tag list

Tags: sxa, components

I want to add `<button>` tag in Rendering Variants tag list so that my link renders as `<button>` and NOT as `<a href>`

When I manually add the button tag in the enum list path (which I don't prefer): /sitecore/system/Settings/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Rendering Variants/Enums/Tags

I get the rendered variant with button as empty

[image]

or

[image]

Is there anyway to render just `<button>` along with all the properties?

Comment: What properties do you want on the button? and why do you want a link rendered as a button. Semantically, if the click changes navigation, it should be an `a` tag.

Comment: Hello @RichardSeal our design team has defined a separate css class each for <button> and <a> tag. But we are trying to resolve this issue. Was also curious to know if we can add some HTML5 elements to the tag list (if required)

Comment: Why not just add the btn css classes to the A tag in your rendering variant. It would look the same and behave properly